# Proof that $f$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2^n} \cos{nx}$$
Proof that $f$ is differentiable on $(-2,2)$

### my approach

let $ m := \frac{x}{2} $ so $m<1$
$$ \left| \frac{x^n}{2^n} \cos{nx}   \right| \le m^n \rightarrow 0 $$
So by comparison we have point convergence. But I don't know how to deal with diffentiable..

Comment: It's not enough that $m^n \to 0$, you need convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty m^n$ to use comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Series of derivatives, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n x^{n - 1} \cos nx - n x^n \sin nx}{2^n}$ converges uniformly on any subsegment of $(-2, 2)$ (per comparison again) and series itself converges. Then the series converges to differentiable function (and it's derivative is sum of series of derivatives) - see, for example, theorem 7.17 of Rudin, "Principles of Mathematical Analysis".

To prove the series is uniformly convergent on $(-2 + \alpha, 2 - \alpha)$, we can note that $|n x^{n - 1} \cos nx - nx^n \sin nx| \leqslant 2 \cdot n \cdot (2 - \alpha)^n$, and it is less then $(2 - \frac{\alpha}{2})^n$ for large enough $n$. And the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2 - \frac{\alpha}{2})^n}{2^n} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{4}\right)^n$ converges.

Comment: how you got $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{n^2 x^{n - 1}}{2^n}\sin nx$?

Comment: By differentiating each term.

Comment: By differentiating each term we get $2^{-n} n x^{n-1} \cos (n
   x)-2^{-n} n x^n \sin (n x) \neq  \frac{n^2 x^{n - 1}}{2^n}\sin nx $

Comment: It was a stupid mistake from me indeed. However correct series of derivatives converges uniformly too.

Comment: how can I prove uniform convergence of that $\sum \frac{n x^{n - 1} \cos nx - n x^n \sin nx}{2^n}$  ? $ \frac{n x^{n - 1} \cos nx - n x^n \sin nx}{2^n} = \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^n}(\cos{nx} - x \sin {nx}) < \frac{3n}{2^n}\cdot 2^{n-1} = \frac{3}{2}n$

Comment: I added a bit more explanation, please say if it's not detailed enough. We don't need uniform convergence on entire $[-2, 2]$, convergence on any interval $[-(2 - \alpha), 2 - \alpha]$ is enough.

Comment: maybe it is obvious but I am not sure why you claim that $|n x^{n - 1} \cos nx - nx^n \sin nx| \leqslant 2 \cdot n \cdot (2 - \alpha)^n$? For sin and cos you put $1$. $n$ you have left, so ok, but there is still $x^{n} - x^{n-1}$

Comment: And $|x| < 2 - \alpha$ as we took interval $(-2 + \alpha, 2 - \alpha)$. Assuming $\alpha < 1$ (we can decrease it if it's not), $|x^n| < (2 - \alpha)^n$ and $|x^{n - 1}| < (2 - \alpha)^n$. And as always $|a - b| \leqslant |a| + |b|$.

Comment: Okay, then we have $\frac{2 \cdot n \cdot (2 - \alpha)^n}{2^n} \rightarrow 0$ Thanks!